# How to get network disconnect event in QFtp?

Tags: qt, ftp, network-programming

How to get network disconnect event in QFtp?

Currently when network goes in disconnect mode, download goes in **pause** mode ( I am not getting any event for this. ), if I connect network after 5 minutes, It resumes again, I want it to either stop or give me network disconnected signal/event.

It would be very helpful if you can give any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect a slot to the signal [`stateChanged`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qftp.html#stateChanged). I guess the state is [`QFtp::Unconnected`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qftp.html#State-enum) when you lose the connection.

Comment: It is not coming, I checked. Is this bug of qt 4.7?

Comment: Don't know if it is a bug but signal should be sent when the server closes the connection unexpectedly (as said in the documentation). Are you sure connection is working fine?

Comment: So it seems to be a bug. You can report it here: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/bughowto.html